# postgres recursive view returning multple rows per input row

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, common-table-expression, recursive-query

**I want a recursive view which reports all children of a given group, one per row.**

I've tried the basic examples from postgres documentation, and modified to try and return multiple rows per recursive step, but I keep ending up with infinite loops.

**Sample Data**

```
create table groups (
       group_id varchar,
       parent_id varchar
       );

insert into groups (group_id, parent_id) values
       ('A',NULL),
       ('B','A'),
       ('C','B'),
       ('D','C'),
       ('E','A')
       ;

--      A
--    /   \
--   E     B
--          \
--           C
--            \
--             D

select * from groups;

group_id |parent_id 
---------|----------
A        |[NULL]    
B        |A         
C        |B         
D        |C
E        |A
```

I want a recursive view which reports each child of a given group, one per row.

**Intended Output**

The vertical white-space is just for clarity.

```
select * from group_recursive;

group_id | parent_id | all_children_ids
---------|-----------|-----------------
A        | NULL      | A        

B        | A         | B
B        | A         | A

E        | A         | E
E        | A         | A

C        | B         | C
C        | B         | B
C        | B         | A

D        | C         | D
D        | C         | C
D        | C         | B
D        | C         | A

select * from group_recursive where all_children_ids = 'A';
A        | NULL      | A
B        | A         | A
E        | A         | A
C        | B         | A
D        | C         | A

select * from group_recursive where all_children_ids = 'B';
B        | A         | B
C        | B         | B
D        | C         | B

select * from group_recursive where all_children_ids = 'D';
D        | C         | D
```

I have to assume this is possible as a view, but if necessary I could change to defining a function or something.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all children of a given group with the following query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select group_id, parent_id, group_id root_id, 0 lvl from groups where group_id = ?
    union all
    select g.group_id, g.parent_id, c.root_id, c.lvl + 1
    from groups g
    inner join cte c on c.group_id = g.parent_id
)
select * from cte order by lvl, group_id
```

The question mark should be replaced with the group whose children you want to exhibit. `all_children` seems like a counter-intuitive column name, so I renamed it `root_id`. As a bonus I added a column called `lvl` that indicates the depth of each group relatively to the root.

On the other hand, if you want to generate all paths up from a given node, as shown in your first resultset, you can traverse the tree upwards:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select group_id, parent_id, group_id root_id, 0 lvl from groups
    union all
    select g.group_id, g.parent_id, c.root_id, c.lvl + 1
    from groups g
    inner join cte c on c.group_id = g.parent_id
)
select group_id, parent_id, root_id from cte order by group_id, parent_id, lvl
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=46d7aa9b383c72191acb22d97389f623)**

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to understand, thanks @GMB. I was nearly there; I hadn't figured out the `group_id root_id` - which was necessary. 

Here's my finished view (trimming out `lvl`; and mangled formatting, I can't figure out code paste in comments). Thanks so much. 

`CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW cte_view (group_id, parent_id, root_id) AS
(      
 select group_id, parent_id, group_id root_id from groups
 union all
 select g.group_id, g.parent_id, c.root_id
 from groups g
 inner join cte_view c on c.group_id = g.parent_id
) 

select * from cte_view order by group_id, parent_id;`

Comment: And I agree-  `root_id` is a much more sensible column name than `all_children_ids`